# SQL joining several tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Yes I know there are some topics with the heading but I really read all of them and couldn't solve the problem.
I have a sql tables shown on sqlfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0aaf72/1

So I want a result like this:
[image]

I mean I want all the data to be as a result, but what i get is all the data but instead of list of series there is written NULL... here is what I tried:

```
SELECT sum(invoiceinput.total) as cons,
   materialtype.`type`,
         materialserie.serie,
         companies.companyName
         FROM invoiceinput JOIN
         invoice ON invoiceinput.invoiceID=invoice.ID JOIN
         companies ON companies.ID=invoice.companiesID JOIN
         materialtype ON materialtype.ID=invoiceinput.materialTypeID LEFT JOIN
         materialserie ON materialserie.ID=invoiceinput.materialTypeID 
         WHERE invoiceinput.materialTypeID 
         GROUP BY materialtype.ID, materialserie.ID, companies.ID, MONTH(21/04/2014)
         ORDER BY MONTH(21/04/2014), companies.ID
```

Comment: can you update sqlfiddle with your sample data to achieve result like above.

Comment: @Dave sorry I couldnt handle it :)

Comment: why i said is because its getting difficult to understand, see think fiddle how he has populated http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7868/0 . if you are able to add it then chances of getting responses are more. however i will also try without data.

Comment: I actualy got the answer: there was a mistake in join: instead of join materialserie ON materialserie.ID=invoiceinput.materialTypeID should be materialserie.ID=invoiceinput.materialserieID

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT sum(invoiceinput.total) as cons,
   materialtype.`type`,
         materialserie.serie,
         companies.companyName
         FROM invoiceinput JOIN
         invoice ON invoiceinput.invoiceID=invoice.ID JOIN
         companies ON companies.ID=invoice.companiesID JOIN
         materialtype ON materialtype.ID=invoiceinput.materialTypeID LEFT JOIN
         materialserie ON materialserie.ID=invoiceinput.materialserieID 
         WHERE invoiceinput.materialTypeID 
         GROUP BY materialtype.ID, materialserie.ID, companies.ID, MONTH(21/04/2014)
         ORDER BY MONTH(21/04/2014), companies.ID
```

so there should be  materialserie ON materialserie.ID=invoiceinput.materialserieID  instead of materialserie ON materialserie.ID=invoiceinput.materialTypeID